# Change font type and size in GNOME 45

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell

I am new to linux and ubuntu. The design of ubuntu with GNOME 45 is beautiful, but I see small things to fix.
System items are very, very nice. But if I install any browser (Edge or Brave) I see large font in favorites, tabs and address bar.
**Where can I change the font size and font family in favorites, tabs, and the address bar?**
I am trying to change it in gnome-shell.css in my template but without much effect.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean just for browsers; you can use gnome theme for browsers.

e.g.: you can use theme for firefox;

https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/firefox-gnome-theme

or you can change you settings. settings > GTK settings.

you can change GTK settings.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GTK

you can look at this: (for gtk themes)
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/gtk-applications-dark-theme

and for system:
Tweaks > Font Panel > Update